# updating layout

Tags: magento-1.7, template, layout

In my project, I am trying to shift positions of two templates in home page of "modern" theme by updating layout in `local.xml` file. The template file names are as follows:

```
1)  frontend\base\default\template\page/switch/languages.phtml

2)  frontend\base\default\template\page/template/links.phtml
```

The above template files are referencing the below block names in layout folder of "base/default".

```
1)  store_language

2)  top.links
```

Both blocks are in same parent block which is "header". So, I wrote the local.xml like this in "default/modern/layout" folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">     
            <remove name="top.links"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="top.linked" as="topLinked" template="page/template/links.phtml" before="store_language"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

The above update layout has removed the block "top.links" successfully but not adding the new block "*top.linked*" again before the "store_language" block. what I am doing wrong here?

For better understanding, please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

I have also some other questions like:

- Does updating of a layout should be done using "local.xml" file only?

Comment: `<reference />` and `<remove />` should both be directly inside the layout update handle (e.g. `<default />`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<remove .. />` directive removes block completely. Even if you are adding it afterwards with the same name it will be still removed.

If you want to remove block from one place and insert it into another you have to do instead is to `unsetChild` first and `insert` it wherever you want.

However this will not help in your case. Those two blocks are echoed inside of `header.phtml` explicitly so it would be much easier just to switch their places there.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how to do it? or just a link would be enough.. :)

Comment: You can try to play with adding one block inside of the other.

Answer (score 2):

if you check the file `template/page/html/header.phtml` you'll notice that all blocks are called using the `getChildHtml` function. This means that, in order to get your `topLinked` block you'll have to add some code in the `header.phtml` file.

```
[...]
<div class="quick-access">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
    <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinked') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
[...]
```

On line 5 I've added your `topLinked` block. This will include the block before `store_language` in the header.

Still removing the old `top.links` and adding a new one won't be required. Just move the `getChildHtml` calls around in the `header.phtml` and you can position them however you want.